# Javascript/GAS: Count the number of object occurrences in JSON response

Tags: javascript, api, loops, google-apps-script, counting

So my function gets time entries from the project system via external API. The condition for summing the time entries is that the approval status need to have some value (> 0). Now I want to add another condition (&&) so that there must be at least an approval status **each** day with a value  (i.e, count the number of approval status to be equal or greater than 5 for the calculation to happen). This is in a bid force user to enter entries for each day of the week. How do I go about this? This what I tried, not sure how to go about it. PS: This calculates for many users.

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var info = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
var content = info.data;
var total_hours = 0;
var count = 0;



for (var j = 0; j < content.length; j++) {
    if (content[j].approvals.data.length > 0 && count >= 5) {

        total_hours += content[j].hours;

    }
}

Logger.log(total_hours)
```

}

sample JSON data

{"paging":{"per_page":20,"page":1,"previous":null,"self":"/api/v1/users/678108/time_entries?assignable_id=&fields=approvals&from=2020-01-20&to=2020-01-24&user_id=678108&page=1","next":"/api/v1/users/678108/time_entries?assignable_id=&fields=approvals&from=2020-01-20&to=2020-01-24&user_id=678108&page=2"},"data":[{"id":1661350010,"assignable_id":2993759,"assignable_type":"Project","user_id":678108,"bill_rate":0.1,"bill_rate_id":37032684,"date":"2020-01-20","hours":0.0,"scheduled_hours":null,"notes":null,"task":null,"is_suggestion":false,"created_at":"2020-01-21T17:32:22Z","updated_at":"2020-01-24T15:08:22Z","approvals":{"paging":{"self":"../time_entries/1661350010/approvals?per_page=0&page=1","next":null,"previous":null,"page":1,"per_page":0},"data":[]}},

Comment: You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function to reach this.

Comment: @demkovych, thanks for looking at the code. Kindly show me how.

Comment: could you share your data?

Comment: @demkovych please look at my edited question for sample JSON response

Comment: Whats a structure of your approvals.data array? There are some object, which has status property?

Comment: @demkovych    Yes, you are right. The approval object has a status property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = [
  {
    "id": 1661350010,
    "assignable_id": 2993759,
    "assignable_type": "Project",
    "user_id": 678108,
    "bill_rate": 0.1,
    "bill_rate_id": 37032684,
    "date": "2020-01-20",
    "hours": 5,
    "scheduled_hours": null,
    "notes": null,
    "task": null,
    "is_suggestion": false,
    "created_at": "2020-01-21T17:32:22Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-01-24T15:08:22Z",
    "approvals": {
      "paging": {
        "self": "../time_entries/1661350010/approvals?per_page=0&page=1",
        "next": null,
        "previous": null,
        "page": 1,
        "per_page": 0
      },
      "data": [{
        'status': 'approved'
      }, {
        'status': 'approved'
      }, {
        'status': 'approved'
      },{
        'status': 'approved'
      },{
        'status': 'approved'
      },{
        'status': 'approved'
      },{
        'status': 'error'
      }]
    }
  }
];

const total = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  const {hours, approvals: {data}} = el;
  if (data.length && data.filter(e => e.status === 'approved').length >= 5) {
    acc += hours;
  }
  return acc;
}, 0);

console.log(total);
```

To make it work in Apps Script and log the result you would have to use the reduce function as follows:

```
const total = data.reduce(function(acc, el) {
  var hours = el.hours;
  var data = el.approvals.data;

  if (data.length && data.filter(function(element) { return element.status === 'approved'}).length >= 5) {
    acc += hours;
  }
  return acc;
}, 0);

Logger.log(total);
```

Comment: Thanks for this @demkovych, however, this flavor of JS doesn't run in Google App Script console (GAS). Am pretty new in javascript and would be happy if you showed me how to make this run in GAS

Comment: I never worked with GAS. You got at idea and need to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: GAS is ES5. No `=>`, `...`